# Basic auth with react rails and device JWT: 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to implement basic authentication in `react` and `rails`

I'm using this gem `gem 'devise-jwt'`

Once a signed up user tried to login I get `Error: Request failed with status code 401`

My `session_controller` looks like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  private

  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render json: resource
  end

  def respond_to_on_destroy
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

And the request from react is:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    const data = this.state
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    axios
      .post(
        'http://192.168.1.21:3000/login',
        {
          user: data,
        },
        { headers },
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

I'm running the server locally in another machine connected to the same network. It works fine in POSTMAN app in the same machine. But when I make the request from a different machine using the IP i get the above error.

One difference I noted is - when using a postman, in the request in rails console password shows as `FILTERED` while when the request is from front-end it is plaintext.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change user:data for data  only in your axios request, data is already an object i suppose with user and password.

Comment: I already tried that. In that case it says user is empty.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that you have to remove the curly braces e.g. url, data if it says empty it means that something is wrong in your react component.